# DB2 trigger illegal token

Tags: triggers, db2

Fairly new to DB2 sql, so forgive my ignorance :)
I have a trigger with a condition inside. I want to then insert some params depending on the condition.. Here it is:

I've looked at DB2 documentation for triggers and also for if statements, and at least to my eyes it appears to comply with it, however i get a -104 error (Illegal symbol token) on the insert line.

The insert works fine provided i use values not from 'N'.

OK, it works if i have nothing in the if then statement.. but only if i have nothing!

Thanks

Comment: Which version of DB2?  For my part, I tend to prefer doing this in one statement, something along the lines of `INSERT INTO DEPO (SELECT ... FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DEPO))`, which has the benefit of being in one of unit-of-work, so you don't have to worry about transactions.

Comment: Your question is useless without the code, so you might as well delete it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that DB2 is confused by your statement terminators. You use a semicolon to terminate the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, but at the same time you use the same terminator inside the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, after the `INSERT`.

In whatever client you use to execute your code, redefine the statement terminator to something else and place that terminator at the end of `CREATE TRIGGER`, after `END ID`. For example, if you use the command line processor, save this to a file `trig.sql`:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTO_INSERT_DEPO_NOMINEE
  AFTER INSERT ON CA_ENTITLEMENT 
  REFERENCING NEW AS N
  FOR EACH ROW

  IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT D.DEPO_CD FROM DEPO D WHERE D.DEPO_CD = N.DEPO_CD)
  THEN    
    INSERT INTO DEPO (DEPO_CD, DEPO_NME, BRANCH_CD, AUTO_GENERATED) 
           VALUES(N.DEPO_CD, NULL, N.BRANCH_CD, 'Y');
  END IF@
```

then run it, specifying "@" as the statement terminator:

```
db2 -td@ -f mytrig.sql
```