# How to create and run a stored procedure for a sql schema with db2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I am taking a database course and am suppose to create a stored procedure for my database in DB2. We were just given a basic idea of a generic stored procedure and told the syntax might vary among vendors like db2, postgres etc.
So I have wrote the following procedure using what we learned in class:

```
Connect to cs***;
CREATE PROCEDURE FRANCHISE_INFO (IN franchID INTEGER)
    LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE at_end INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE vfranchID INTEGER;
    DECLARE vownerID INTEGER; 
    DECLARE vname VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE vemail VARCHAR(30); 
    DECLARE not_found CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000';

    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT F.franchiseID, O.ownerID, O.name, O.email
        FROM Franchise F, Owner O
        WHERE F.franchiseID = franchID AND F.ownerID = O.ownerID;
        DECLARE CONTINUE_HANDLER FOR not_found SET at_end = 1;
        OPEN C1;
        FETCH C1 INTO vfranchID, vownerID, vname, vemail;
        WHILE @at_end = 0 DO
            IF(O.name == NULL)
                THEN UPDATE owner SET O.name = 'R McDonald' WHERE O.ownerID = vownerID; 
            END IF;
            IF(O.email == NULL)
                THEN UPDATE owner SET O.email = 'headoffice@mcdonald.ca' WHERE O.ownerID = vownerID;
            END IF;
            FETCH C1 INTO vfranchID, vownerID, vname, vemail;
        END WHILE;
        CLOSE C1;
END 
@
```

I have saved this in a file named `storedproc.sql` and trying to compile it on the terminal using

```
db2 -t -f storedproc.sql
```

but i get the following

```
Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3
 SQL authorization ID   = CS******
 Local database alias   = CS***


DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "nd 
INTEGER DEFAULT 0".  Expected tokens may include:  "<psm_semicolon>".  LINE 
NUMBER=4.  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "INTEGER" was found following "DECLARE vfranchID 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  LINE NUMBER=1.  
SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "INTEGER" was found following "DECLARE vownerID 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  LINE NUMBER=1.  
SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DECLARE vname VARCHAR" was found following 
"BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<compile_fragment>".  
LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DECLARE vemail VARCHAR" was found following 
"BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<compile_fragment>".  
LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'02000'" was found following "NDITION FOR 
SQLSTATE".  Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  LINE NUMBER=1.  
SQLSTATE=42601

DB21031E  The SQL statement using the cursor "C1" ("SQLCUR1") returned:
SQL0206N  "FRANCHID" is not valid in the context where it is used.  
SQLSTATE=42703

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "<space>" was found following 
"CONTINUE_HANDLER".  Expected tokens may include:  "FOR".  LINE NUMBER=1.  
SQLSTATE=42601

DB21028E  The cursor "C1" has not been declared.

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "INTO" was found following "<identifier>".  
Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "WHILE" was found following 
"BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<variable_set>".  
SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END IF". 
Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "=" was found following "IF(O.email =".  
Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END IF". 
Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".  SQLSTATE=42601

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "INTO" was found following "<identifier>".  
Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END 
WHILE".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21028E  The cursor "C1" has not been declared.


DB21007E  End of file reached while reading the command.
```

I have been searching the web to find what the entire process of setting up a stored procedure but no luck. I do not understand if i am using the wrong syntax for my procedure, or am i setting it up wrong. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750346/db2-trigger-illegal-token/21755347#21755347

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DB2 expects the stored procedure to be terminated (finished) by a semicolon by default. You followed good practice and used the `@` to end that `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, now you have to tell DB2.

`db2 -td@ -f storedproc.sql`

The `-td@` tells DB2 to use the `@` as statement terminator. Thereafter make sure that all statements in your file end with that terminator.

You could also set the terminator within that file.

Comment: Still getting an error `[cs421***][comp***][~] db2 -td@ -t storedproc.sql
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following 
"storedproc.sql".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".  
SQLSTATE=42601`

Comment: You have "-td@ -t", remove the second "-t"

Comment: `[cs421***][comp***][~] db2 -td@ -f storedproc.sql
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "CREATE" was found following "<identifier>".  
Expected tokens may include:  "USER".  SQLSTATE=42601`
getting the above now, any advice?

Comment: you are mixing terminators: the `connect` uses semicolon, the `create procedure` the `@`. Change the `connect` to end with @

Comment: @SSRed -- are you trying to run the OS command `db2` as an SQL statement in some sort of a GUI client, by chance?

Comment: @data_henrik thanks a ton, I changed it to `connect to cs***@;` and it now goes through the code, still getting an error `SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DECLARE CONTINUE_HANDLER FOR not_" was found 
following "nerID = O.ownerID;  ".  Expected tokens may include:  
"<psm_set_token>".  LINE NUMBER=14.  SQLSTATE=42601`  I am guessing i messed up my logic somewhere or messed up my declare statement. Also any suggestions on what's a good resource for novices to learn db2 syntax for procedural statement? @mustaccio,i am running it via terminal after sshing into a linux machine withmy schema and db2

Comment: The best way to learn about the syntax is the reference :) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.kc.doc/welcome.html Look for CREATE PROCEDURE. Please mark the question complete

Comment: thanks for all your help, solved my problem it was the underscore in CONTINUE_HANDLER.